# how to do this in new version(React.CreateElement)

Tags: reactjs, function, typeerror, createelement

My code causes the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: React.CreateElement is not a function
>       at index.html:11

[image]

Comment: Please consider adding your source code as text. It's easier to copy and answer than an image.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to import React at the top of your file:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: This is not required when loading React via script tags directly. The script loading will define `React` in global scope.

Comment: ok @MaazSyedAdeeb my answer was before the OP had posted his code.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems in your code:

1. The `render` API is available in `ReactDOM` and not `React`.
2. You have a typo. There is no `CreateElement`, it's `createElement`.

Working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script>
    ReactDOM.render(
      React.createElement('p', null, 'Hello, world!'),
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You could just follow [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html) to create your HTML page or use `create-react-app` or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io). More details on how to try out React [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#try-react).